# How do I calculate the integral of inequalities

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

$x^4≤y≤\sqrt{x}$

So I was given that plane set, I found the range to be from [0,1] so I assumed we would have to calculate the integral on that interval, though I can't reason how to actually calculate it, given that the correct answer is supposed to be $C_{area}= \frac7{15}$

Answer (score 1):

It is not an "integral of inequalities."  It is instead an integral *with limits*.

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 (\sqrt{x} - x^4)\ dx = \left( \frac{2 x^{3/2}}{3} - \frac{x^5}{5} \right) \Bigg|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{7}{15}$$

Comment: Thank you for the graph, it really made things clear